# What is the difference between principle and authentication in this example?

Tags: spring-security

I am learning Spring Security and can't understand what's the difference between authentication and principal. I do understand that the code below is not logically connected, but as far as I understand both *authentication* and *principal* gives us possibility to get the data from the currently logged user.

```
@PreFilter("filterObject.owner == authentication.name")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') or principal.userId == #id")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Principal represents the logged in User. Spring's `Authentication` interface extends the `Principal` interface, so Authentication `is a` Principal.

Before the user has been authenticated, Authentication can represent the token for an authentication request.

After the user has been authenticated, it can provide extra information about the Principal e.g. through `getAuthorities(..)` you can get the authorities that the principal has been granted, after successful authentication.

Comment: May be valuable to add this link: [Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-authentication)